# Excel VBA - Update column A with a value if column B contains any value. If column B contains no values then do not run the macro

Tags: vba, excel

In my scenario I have four columns, columns A-D. If column B contains any value whatsoever then the matching row in column A must be updated to contain a predetermined value. The same macro is applied for columns C and D. I have code right now that achieves that result:

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value1()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=If(B1<>"""",""PREDETERMINED VALUE"","""")"
        .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

When column B contains a value the macro will write "PREDETERMINED VALUE" in the corresponding cell in column A.

An issue occurs when a column does not contain any values at all. What happens is the macro will write my new value to nearly all of the blank cells in the entire data-set.

Thank you in advance for your time! I apologize if my question is noobish, I am still very new to VBA.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem but I think you need to change this line as you want to base it on the values in A rather than B `lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Another problem is that the first instance of your formula will refer to B1 but the blank may not be in row 1.

Comment: Hello, @SJR

I am sorry if my requirements were not stated clearly enough I can provide screenshots of what I am attempting to achieve.

Your modification to the code was not what i was looking for. When I ran it the code update column A even though column B was empty.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. If col B is all blank and there are blanks in A it will put the formula in those blanks in A (which will return an empty string because B is blank). I don't see how it can put values in A unless what appear to be blanks in B are not actually blank.

Comment: Perhaps you could share with me the code you are testing? I am not getting the same results as you.

Comment: I'm using the code above, plus the change I suggested in first comment. Perhaps you can post a screenshot of your sheet?

Comment: I found the answer!


`Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B:B")) = 1 Then

    Else
    
        With ws
            lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=If(LEN(RC2),""Answer"", TEXT(,))"
            .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub`

Comment: @UserX:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should post that as an "answer" and then "accept" that answer so others don't read through your post thinking it's still unanswered.  It's a common courtesy for others on the forum.

Comment: @abraxascarab Thanks for pointing that out to me! I posted that code as a separate comment and I will accept that answer when I am allowed to. For some reason StackOverflow wants me to wait one day before I can accept that comment as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B:B")) = 1` in the comment section to avoid the problem is a good attempt but there can be exceptions as discussed below. Test it several times using various scenarios (especially using blank range) to see if you are getting the desired result every single time.

`.SpecialCells` attempts to simplify the codes, however sometime [the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` VBA function does not work as expected in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/832293/the-specialcells-xlcelltypeblanks-vba-function-does-not-work-as-expect).

Also, the statement `On Error Resume Next` shouldn't be used as far as practicable. But if you must, be sure to insert the `On Error GoTo 0` statement ASAP as you don't want to mask other errors.

Instead of `.SpecialCells`, you may use `For Each` loop to avoid this problem. So let's see how it looks:

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value1()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Long, r As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each r In .Range("A1:A" & lRow)
            If IsEmpty(r) Then
                r.Formula = "=If(B" & r.Row & "<>"""",""PREDETERMINED VALUE"","""")"
                r = r.Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution but I found a solution that works for me. I tested multiple scenarios and it works every time. Please check it out and leave feedback if you would like!

Comment: sry mate it didnt. pl see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhjuJ.png). only data before macro run was in cell `G7`. after the macro run, whole range `A1:G7` except cell `G7` was populated with zeros. but anyway, it's your choice as long as you are aware of the associated risk

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer everyone!

```
Sub Update_Column_Based_On_Column_Value_1()
    On Error Resume Next
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lRow As Long

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Range("B:B")) = 1 Then

        Else

            With ws
                lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A1:A" & lRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=If(LEN(RC2),""NEW TEXT HERE"", TEXT(,))"
                .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value
            End With
        End If
    End Sub
```